# RAID 6 array, one disk rebuilding?

Tags: supermicro, raid6, jbod

I have got a 10 disk (16 TB) RAID-6 array (AVAGO MegaRAID SAS 9380-8e) in a Supermicro JBOD enclosure. The controller started beeping today and one disk is blinking red/blue. I entered the AVAGO control software and 9 of the disks are shown as "Online", while one of them is shown as "Rebuild" with a Progress of 20%.

My question is: What does it mean that the disk is rebuilding? I expected that I would have to swap the failed disk before anything can be rebuild.

Thanks for your help!
Gregor

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Disks can experience temporary failures that cause them to drop out of the array but can be corrected by a system reboot or controller reset. This might really be a one-off error but I would follow up with `smartctl` or a vendor utility to confirm that the disk isn't on the point of permanently failing.

If your disk is continuously in a state where it is being rebuilt then this may indicate that the disc is *irreparable*. At this point you will need to replace the disk to allow the degraded RAID array to complete the rebuilding process.

- Many departments will follow a policy of replacing any disk that goes into a rebuilding state spontaneously as that indicates a high risk of further impending failures in the future.